# RTE editor looses all tags an save

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, rte

I have a strange problem with the rte-editor. a small installation recently updated from TYPO3 7 to 8, no special CEs, CSC and still rtehtmlarea:
each time a normal CE (CType = text) is saved all html-tags inside `bodytext` disappear.

*especially:*
there was/is a list of links

```
<ul>
   <li><a ...>text1</a></li>
   <li><a ...>text2</a></li>
</ul>
```

which gets converted to

```
<p>text1 text2</p>
```

This happens with `ext:rtehtmlarea` and also with `ext:rte_ckeditor`.
It also happens even without any RTE editor (you get a *naked* textarea input, where you can enter HTML)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the RTE configuration in TSconfig was missing some important allowances.

```
RTE.default {
    :

    proc {
        allowTagsOutside = address, article, aside, blockquote, footer, header, hr, nav, section, ul, ol
        entryHTMLparser_db = 1
        entryHTMLparser_db {
            allowTags = a, abbr, acronym, address, article, aside, b, bdo, big, blockquote, br, caption, center, cite, code, col, colgroup, dd, del, dfn, dl, div, dt, em, font, footer,header, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, hr, i, img, ins, kbd, label, li, link, meta, nav, ol, p, pre, q, samp, sdfield, section, small,span, strike, strong, style, sub, sup, table, thead, tbody, tfoot, td, th, tr, title, tt, u, ul, var
        }
        exitHTMLparser_db = 1
        exitHTMLparser_db {
            htmlSpecialChars = 0
            keepNonMatchedTags = 1
        }
    }
}
```